# Why window.resizeTo() function is not resizing window at the smaller then given values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, window-resize, eel

I am building an app using python-eel in chrome mode (**Front end :** in *HTML, CSS & JS*). The problem is I use a function which resize the window on resizing the window so that my app content looks good (without extra space & some hidden content.

JavaScript code :-

```
sideBar.style.display="none";    // Hiding aside bar on startup
function setsize(){
    if (sideBar.style.display != "none"){window.resizeTo(510,600);}    // If aside is shown/open
    else{window.resizeTo(310,600);};    // If aside is hidden
};
function showaside(){    // Function for hiding or unhiding the aside
    if(sideBar.style.display != "none"){
        sideBar.style.display = "none";
    }
    else{
        sideBar.style.display = "block";
    };
setsize();
```

But the problem is when I start the app, window is resized to 295px x 561px but size which I set is 310px x 600px.

**Note :** *This problem is only occurring in Windows10, when I tried to run my app in Ubuntu (linux), it is working according to my desire*.

Please let me know where this problem is occurring, Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing this problem for a long, but now I have found a way to adjust screen size of python-eel window which not only works in Windows also gives exact size in Linux. Even in which mode you use, such as: chrome, edge etc.

JavaScript :

```
function setsize(){
    var y = 600;
    var x;
    if(sideBar.style.display != "none"){x = 510;}
    else{x = 310};
    
    if(window.innerWidth != x || window.innerHeight != y){
        window.resizeTo(x,y);
        var width = x - window.innerWidth;    //innerWidth is read only
        var height=y - window.innerHeight;    //innerHeight is also read only
        window.resizeTo(x + width, y + height);
    };
};
```

This all is just because this JavaScript function resize the python-eel window according to outer width and height this function will adjust the height according to inner width and height.

I hope this will helpful for you.